# pip install simple-draw происходит ошибка

Tags: python, pip, simple-draw

````sh
C:\Users\Yan>pip install simple-draw
Collecting simple-draw
  Using cached simple_draw-2.8.0.tar.gz (7.5 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pygame==2.1.2 (from simple-draw)
  Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [61 lines of output]


      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
      Using WINDOWS configuration...

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wo0a2fhx\pygame_661daa016c3a4c9a9dfccdf347076bd0\setup.py", line 359, in <module>
          buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wo0a2fhx\pygame_661daa016c3a4c9a9dfccdf347076bd0\buildconfig\config.py", line 225, in main
          deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wo0a2fhx\pygame_661daa016c3a4c9a9dfccdf347076bd0\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 497, in main
          and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wo0a2fhx\pygame_661daa016c3a4c9a9dfccdf347076bd0\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 290, in ask
          update(x86=x86, x64=x64)
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wo0a2fhx\pygame_661daa016c3a4c9a9dfccdf347076bd0\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 273, in update
          download_prebuilts(download_dir, x86=x86, x64=x64)
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wo0a2fhx\pygame_661daa016c3a4c9a9dfccdf347076bd0\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 124, in download_prebuilts
          download_sha1_unzip(url, checksum, temp_dir, 1)
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wo0a2fhx\pygame_661daa016c3a4c9a9dfccdf347076bd0\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 54, in download_sha1_unzip
          response = urllib.urlopen(request).read()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
          return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
          response = meth(req, response)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
          response = self.parent.error(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
          return self._call_chain(*args)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
          result = func(*args)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
          raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
      urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
      Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip ed561079ec622b0bab5a9e02976f5d540b0622da
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip 1436df41ebc47ac36e02ec9bda5699e80ff9bd27
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip 9097148f4529cf19f805ccd007618dec280f0ecc
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.pygame.org/ftp/jpegsr9d.zip ed10aa2b5a0fcfe74f8a6f7611aeb346b06a1f99

      ---
      For help with compilation see:
          https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
      To contribute to pygame development see:
          https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
      ---

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.```
````

Answer (score 0):

под линуксом работает

```
# pip3.11 install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-2.3.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (13.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.8/13.8 MB 880.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-2.3.0



# python3.11
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 03 2023, 18:48:37) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pygame
pygame 2.3.0 (SDL 2.24.2, Python 3.11.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>>
```

в вашем случае можно предложить установку anaconda, решающую проблему установки модулей, требующих двоичных библиотек, что часто и является основной проблемой при установке модулей.

Comment: В вопросе указывается `simple-draw`, не?

Comment: @PeterKolosov по тексту ошибки видно, что не удается установить pygame (это одна из зависимостей simple-draw). Но в принципе этот ответ не решает проблему с установкой под windows.

Comment: ну, тогда совсем не установится, косяки релиза, тем более питон 3.11, см. ошибки на github